# Suppress the passphrase prompt in GPG command

Tags: prompt, gnupg, passphrase

### Edited Version

I have a question about GPG, but I write all of the process, maybe it will help someone.

I want to: **Suppress the passphrase prompt in GPG command.** I don't want to: **use -c option (--symmetric).**

I have 2 systems Linux and Windows. I want to send the data from Linux to Windows. I want to encrypt the data in Linux and decrypt in Windows.

- `myFileOnLinux.txt` is a file on Linux that I want to encrypt.
- `my@Email.com` the UID of pair key.
- `myPasswordPhrase` is the password phrase.

I installed GPG on both and did the steps:

1. Generate a pair key in `Windows`:

   ```
   gpg --gen-key
   ```
2. Change the key parameter in `Windows`:

   ```
   gpg --edit-key my@Email.com
   ```

   ```
   trust
   5
   expire
   0
   ```
3. Export the public keys:

   ```
   gpg -a --export my@Email.com > public.key
   ```
4. Send the public key to the Linux machine.
5. Import the public key in Linux.

   ```
   gpg --import public.key
   ```
6. Change the trust parameter in Linux

   ```
   gpg --edit-key my@Email.com
   ```

   ```
   trust
   5
   ```
7. Encrypt a file in Linux

   ```
   gpg --output output.enc --encrypt --recipient my@Email.com myFileOnLinux.txt
   ```
8. Send the encrypted file to Windows.
9. Decrypt the file.

   ```
   gpg --batch --passphrase "myPasswordPhrase" -d -o test.dec output.enc
   ```

In Windows with a popup window it asked me the `Passphrase` again. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Try `--passphrase-file` option.

Comment: The same problem :(

Comment: Found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase

Comment: @i486 Thanks, but as I mentioned, I don't want use -c as option.

Comment: @MalusJan were you able to get this resolved? I am facing similar issue on gnupg2.x for Windows.

Comment: @ditty unfortunately not. I used -c option 

Comment: @MalusJan what is the -c option?

Comment: @Ditty -c, --symmetric
Encrypt with symmetric cipher only This command asks for a passphrase. Like have just one password (there is not private and public password). Look at the link for more options [Link](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html#sec-2-4)

Comment: @Ditty look at the answer that Marc wrote down.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found this command which disables the entry prompt on windows(works also for *nix systems):

```
--pinentry-mode=loopback
```

The full command would be:

```
gpg --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase  "PASSWORD" -d -o "PATH\TO\OUTPUT" "PATH\TO\FILE.gpg"
```

Comment: OMG I have been wasting hours trying to figure this out.  Every answer out there is either using an older version of gpg where the passphrase/batch options used to work in windows, or they are linux users where those options still work.  THANK YOU.

Comment: GPG 1.4.7 was working fine with "--batch" switch to suppress interactive command. For GPG 2.2+ "--batch" switch did not work but "--pinentry-mode=loopback" worked to suppress passphrase window while running command. Thanks for solution!

Comment: This worked.  However the "--batch" and "--yes" switch I had to keep.  If the destination file existed then the overwrite pop up would hold up the process.  So adding those two switches automatically suppressed and answered yes to overwrite.

Comment: @sunpack `--pinentry-mode=loopback` works fine for me with and without `--batch` and `--yes` on gpg v2.2.20, also in conjunction with `--passphrase-fd 0` and piping in the passphrase. `--batch` and `--yes` alone did not work for me either as @mayank-jha already mentioned above.

Comment: Let's see what man say:   

`If this command (--quick-gen-key) is used with --batch, --pinentry-mode has been set to loopback, and one of the passphrase options (--passphrase, --passphrase-fd, or passphrase-file) is used, the  sup-
              plied passphrase is used for the new key and the agent does not ask for it. `

Answer (score 5):

```
gpg --batch --import sec.key
gpg -d --batch --passphrase mypassphrase encrypted_file.gpg
```

the ***--batch*** flag supresses the passphrase prompt while importing keys as well as while decrypting the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use symmetric keys (-c option) then you just need to add the `--quiet` and `--batch` flags.

Here is a full working example:

```
gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 --passphrase mySuperCoolPassphrase --quiet file_to_encrypt.tftpl
```

github also has a working example of this which they use to decrypt the file in an automation
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#limits-for-secrets

`UPDATE`

There is an issue with gpg decryption that made me think twice about using it in production. (Basically it hangs indefinitely unless you manually tinker with it) so I've decided to go with https://github.com/FiloSottile/age instead as it is simple to use, highly rated, and seems very reliable