# SSIS PGP decryption - How to enter Passphrase without the popup window?

Tags: ssis, gnupg, pgp

I have a file with `pgp` encryption. I want to decrypt the file using SSIS. Whenever I run the package it prompts me to enter passphrase. How can I bypass this?

I'm using execute process task to run the decrypt command from command prompt.

```
\C echo XXXXXXXXX|gpg --keyring "\\LSRSQL08\Share\DataServices_Key\public.pgp" --secret-keyring "\\LSRSQL08\Share\DataServices_Key\private.pgp" --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 -o \\LSRSQL08\Share\WorkingFolders\ACXM\DataLoad\Razor_FEB21_Install.txt -d \\LSRSQL08\Share\WorkingFolders\ACXM\Razor_FEB21_Install.txt.pgp
```

I have extracted public and private key like below:

```
gpg --output public.pgp --armor --export DataServices@company.com
gpg --output private.pgp --armor --export-secret-key DataServices@company.com
```

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50334044/8408335) applies.

Comment: @vhoang, `--pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase XXXXXX  -o \\LSRSQL08\Share\WorkingFolders\ACXM\DataLoad\Razor_FEB21_Install.txt -d \\LSRSQL08\Share\WorkingFolders\ACXM\DataLoad\Razor_FEB21_Install.txt.pgp` is working fine from VS/ CMD/ GPG. However, when I run same package from SSISDB Catalog or SQL Server Agent Job it fails on decrypting part. It runs for 4-5 minutes and fails eventually. Looks like it is popping up passphrase windows in backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below command worked for me. Just we need to make sure that we import the key in same account under which SSIS package will be running.

```
--pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase XXXXXX  -o \\LSRSQL08\Share\WorkingFolders\ACXM\DataLoad\Razor_FEB21_Install.txt -d \\LSRSQL08\Share\WorkingFolders\ACXM\DataLoad\Razor_FEB21_Install.txt.pgp
```